# Bug on calling a dynamic array function

Tags: c

I have bug when calling to a function `dynamic_arr` - somehow I loose all my array and only
the first element being returned.

In my code my `main` calls a function that dynamically needs to create an array
and after the user will insert the elements of the array all the array needs to be passed to 
function `funcdosomthing`.

But at the moment function `funcdosomthing` gets only the first element and not all the array.

Just to make clear that everything else works - when I don't use function `dynamic_arr` and
set the array manualy `int a[] = {1, 0, 2};` everything works fine and function `funcdosomthing` gets all the array with 3 elements.

Here's my code:

```
int *dynamic_arr(int n)
{
    int i, *a;
    a = (int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int));
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) scanf("%d",a+i);
    return a;
}

int mainprograma()
{
    int n,*a,i;

    scanf("%d",&n);
    a=dynamic_arr(n);

    funcdosomthing(a, sizeof a / sizeof a[0]);
    ...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are trying to calculate the size of an array from a pointer to a dynamic array.

```
sizeof a / sizeof a[0]
```

In C you simply cannot find out the length of an array if you only have a pointer to the array. The code you are using is appropriate if you have an *array*, but you don't have an array, you have a *pointer*.

So, if you had declared `a` like this

```
int a[3];
```

or this

```
int a[] = {0, 1, 2};
```

then `a` would be an *array* rather than a *pointer* and the `sizeof` code above would be applicable.

Fortunately you know how big the dynamic array is because you just created it. It has `n` elements. So you must write your call to `funcdosomthing` like this:

```
funcdosomthing(a, n);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you try to find the size when you already know the size?!

You should use `n` instead of calculating the size like `sizeof a / sizeof a[0]`. And more over, `sizeof(a)` will give your expected result iff `a` is an array. In this case, it is a `pointer-to-memory-which-can-store-n-integers`.